# Where Can I check if vuejs3 support those dependencies

Tags: html, user-interface, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have `vuejs2` project with next dependencies,

[image: dependencies]

Where can I check if `vuejs3` supports them?

Also tell me your opinion, how can I update `vuejs2` project with this dependencies to `vuejs3`?

Comment: You need to go through each of them and check their repo/readme/documentation if Vue3 is supported. This is because Vue3 saw the deprecation of several Vue2 features that many plugins may rely on (such as events), so it's not a matter of simply porting a Vue2 plugin over to Vue3.